Negating brackets in a C scanf() scanset
I'm trying to use scanf() to read lines of the form mov r0, r1, r2 or ldr r0, [r1, 0x4] in a text buffer, negating any possible square brackets, commas and white spaces. The following code is not working:
void ReadBuffer(const char* buffer)
{
 char command[2048];
 char var[3][2048];
 sscanf(buffer,"%[^ ,[]\n\t] %[^ ,[]\n\t], %[^ ,[]\n\t], %[^ ,[]\n\t]", command, va[0], var[1], var[2]);
}

How can I add the square brackets to the negated scanset?

"The following code is not working:" - exactly how do you try to use the code? What happens when you try this, and how is that different from what you expect to happen?

C 2018 describes the scanf conversion specifiers in 7.21.6.2 12, and for the [ conversion it says:

… If the conversion specifier begins with [] or [^], the right bracket character is in the scanlist and the next following right bracket character is the matching right bracket that ends the specification; otherwise the first following right bracket character is the one that ends the specification…

Therefore, put the ] immediately after the ^. The [ may go anywhere in the scanlist (the characters between the [ and the closing ]).
Example:
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    char a[100], b, c[100], d, e[100], f;
    int result = sscanf("foo[bar, baz]", " %[^][, ] %c %[^][, ] %c %[^][, ] %c", a, &b, c, &d, e, &f);
    printf("scanf returned %d.\n", result);
    printf("a = %s.\n", a);
    printf("b = %c.\n", b);
    printf("c = %s.\n", c);
    printf("d = %c.\n", d);
    printf("e = %s.\n", e);
    printf("f = %c.\n", f);
}

Output:

scanf returned 6.
a = foo.
b = [.
c = bar.
d = ,.
e = baz.
f = ].

Note this is a painstaking way to parse assembly code. It is usually better to write your own C code to analyze the characters, especially after studying some parsing theory, and even better to use an off-the-shelf lexical analyzer generator and a grammar parser generator. Doing it with scanf requires careful attention to return values, buffer sizes, and more.

Thank you for your reply. Your solution worked for me for the closing bracket, but not for the opening one. The function stops reading the buffer as soon as it finds the opening bracket.
